# Reload of Firefox bookmarks favicons

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, favicon

After updating my Firefox from version 12 to version 13, my bookmarks favicons have gone.

I wonder whether it's possible to force the browser to only download/refresh the favicons for all my bookmarks without visiting the websites themselves.

Comment: [CheckPlaces](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkplaces/) will do the job. But its gone. :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experiences with [FavIcon Reloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/faviconreloader/), but unfortunately it's sometimes very hard to find exactly how to bring up its window.

Currently, you can right click on one of your bookmarks on the Bookmark Toolbar to bring up a menu, this should have an option to bring up the FavIcon Reloader window.

Comment: Reloader has now been removed and is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Current Add-on that does the job: [Checkmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkmarks-web-ext/reviews)

It will literally load X bookmarks at a time into tabs (I guess that's what has to be done, unfortunately... I'd think it could just go to `/favicon.ico` but whatever...), and then close the tabs when finished getting the favicon. It also does retries etc. which is all configurable. You have to open it in the Sidebar. It works pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

In the Firefox Bookmarks Manager you can right click `Bookmarks Toolbar` under `All Bookmarks`, and select `Open all in tabs`. It still visits the websites, but at least you don't have to visit each website separately.

Comment: {Chuckle}  And then watch as your Firefox session crawls to a halt and explodes after it opens a few hundred or thousand tabs.    Yay!  `BOOM`.  Good answer, but mine would self-combust!!

Comment: Thanks. Best solution so far. :) I had 55 tabs to load :)

Comment: I have several thousand bookmarks so that is definitely not a viable solution.